# Hey what is the datatype I am looking for?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm pretty sure it actually exists haha

But in sql it is a field and inside it has data1,data2,data3 and so on. Like an array inside a field. Any idea?

Comment: Data types are RDBMS dependent -- what is your RDBMS? Secondly, all column values in a normalized table should be atomic, that is, single-valued. It is rarely correct to store an array of values in a single field.

Comment: sql sorry. Hope this helps :)

Comment: SQL is not an RDBMS, it's a language supported by a large number of RDBMS's. Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres?

Comment: Ok sorry you have lost me. I am just typing sql into php my admin. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a PHP application for managing MySQL servers... if you're going to come into a community of professional programmers and ask for their help, at least try to act like an adult. "I'm pretty sure it actually exists haha" is a little below the bar here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said befor. No such type.

And you should not keep comma separated values in a field. Instead create another table for the the id-value pairs.

Lets say you have a blog, where you use an `Articles` table. Each article can have multiple `Tags`. Instead of keeping all the tags for said article in single field as comma separated values, you should have table structure like this:

```
 table: Articles         table: Tags         table: ArticleTags
 ----------------        --------------      -----------------
| article_id  PK |      | tag_id    PK |    | article_id   FK |
| title          |      | name         |    | tag_id       FK |
| content        |      |              |    |                 |
|                |       --------------      -----------------
 ----------------
```

In addition `ArticleTags` table would have a composite primary key, made from both article and tag ids - `PRIMARY KEY( article_id , tag_id )`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such data type.

You can put data like that in a regular varchar field, but then it will be complicated to use in any query, because there is no built in way to access comma separated items.

The usual way to handle data like that is to put it in another table.

Comment: Ok can I just grab a bit of help?

INSERT into updates (ufrom,userid,message)
SELECT userid,friendid,"lol" FROM friends where userid=4 and friendid != "0"

is my current query how do I get all results from userid and parse them with commas?